# jetty server refusing connections from 127.0.0.1

Tags: jetty, connection, maven-jetty-plugin

Not sure what's going on here exactly, but my local jetty server that I'm running via the maven plugin, as in:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mortbay.jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <systemProperty>
                        <name>webapp.env.name</name>
                        <value>local</value>
                    </systemProperty>
                </systemProperties>
                <stopPort>8080</stopPort>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

... is refusing all connections from 127.0.0.1...

For instance, if I run **curl 'http://localhost:8080'** I get a valid html response pointing at the contents of my webapp directory.  But **curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8080'** returns **curl: (52) Empty reply from server**.  Does anyone out there know how I might configure jetty properly to accept such connections?  This is complicating our dev team's local configurations quite a bit.

Thanks!

Comment: why can't you just point to localhost?

Comment: Because we're doing FB app development, which requires devs to map a made up domain name a la blah.blahblah.com to 127.0.0.1 in their /etc/hosts, in order to wrap their local instances within the FB container...